# I want to upload multiple images to server using Rx Java and Retrofit and want to call onNext once all they get successfully uploaded

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I want to upload multiple images to server using retrofit/RxJava one after one, not in parallel. I want to get response once they all got uploaded successfully. I need this result in Array List.

**Code For Single Image upload**

```java
@Multipart
@POST("addImage")
Observable<ImageUploadResponse> savePhoto(@Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

**Response from server**

```
{
   "isSuccess":true,
   "isError":false,
   "message":"You are successfully added image",
   "payLoad":{
      "imagePath":"public\/ContainerItem\/vTpjFdTNHj5QK6rKrBuuiwWG3SYKp1PxxpOJmKIE.jpeg",
      "updated_at":"2018-04-27 07:34:37",
      "created_at":"2018-04-27 07:34:37",
      "id":389
   }
}
```

I want to know which RxJava operators to be used in the case where I want the result once all images are uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Collecting the results into a list can be done with `toList`.  Assuming your images are saved in a `List` named `imageList`, you can do something like --

```
Observable.fromIterable(imageList)
        .flatMap(image -> service.savePhoto(image))
        .toList()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(...)
```